# AngularJS $rootScope variable exists, but not accessible

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, rootscope

I set a $rootScope variable in one of my modules and now want to access that same $rootScope variable in another module. Thus far I can see that in both modules the variable has been set properly, but when I try accessing the variable in $rootScope, I only get undefined.

How can I access this variable without doing a factory/service workaround? The variable is really simple and $rootScope should suffice for what I need. I've put some generic sample code below to illustrate the issue:

file1.js

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp1', []);

app.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.myFunc = function() {
        $rootScope.test = 1;
    }
}
```

file2.js

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp2', []);

app.controller('Ctrl2', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.need_to_access_this = $rootScope.test; // undefined
    console.log($rootScope); // returns JS object w/ test property set to 1
}
```

Comment: Are the modules on separate parts of the dom?

Comment: Put this in a plunkr or something. Impossible to help without an example implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I was just stuck in the same problem when I figured out that you have define those properties for $rootScope before the controllers or services load. So what I did was set inital values when the application runs. In your case it will be like:

```
app.run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.test="variable";
})
```

`

Answer (score 1):

In `Ctrl1` the $rootScope.test value is set inside the $scope.myFunc.

The problem is that you aren't calling that function, so the `test` property in $rootScope is never set.

You need to call `$scope.myFunc();` in `Ctrl1` or set `$rootScope.test = 1;` dirrectly in the Controller:

```
app.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.myFunc = function() {
        $rootScope.test = 1;
    };

    $scope.myFunc();
}
```

or

```
app.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.test = 1;
}
```

EDIT:

The above suggestions still remain valid, thus you need to call myFunc().

But the problem with your code is that `Ctrl1` belongs to `MyApp1` and `Ctrl2` belongs to `MyApp2`.

**Every application has a single root scope** ([docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24rootScope))

You will need to create `Ctrl2` as a controller of `MyApp1`:

```
angular.module('MyApp1')
    .controller('Ctrl2', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.need_to_access_this = $rootScope.test; // undefined
        console.log($rootScope); // returns JS object w/ test property set to 1
    }]);
```